# Repeat Activities

Tags: activity

The final confirmation screen of repeat activities isn't being generated when following the instructions in the user guide and the activities aren't being generated in the system. Has anyone encountered this and what the cause might be?

Comment: When reporting an issue such as this it can be helpful to see if you can replicate it either on one of the demo sites https://civicrm.org/demo or the version running the latest code at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

Comment: Welcome Beth! I just tested on the latest version and it seems to be working. Maybe you're on an old version, or you have an extension that is interfering.  Could you please edit your question to give your CiviCRM version?  If that's not the issue, I recommend a) installing the Log Viewer extension from **Administer menu » Extensions, Add New**; b) noting the most recent log entry in **Administer menu » Administration Console » View Log**, c) try creating the activities again, and d) looking for new log entries.  Edit your question to include them and folks can help you better!